# Usar dropzone.js con asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, drag-and-drop

Quiero subir multiples archivos utilizando dropzone.js y tomar las rutas de los archivos para almacenarlos en mi base de datos, pero he encontrado muy poca informacion al respecto o solo para MVC, alguien que ya lo haya utilizado y me pudiese ayudar.

Comment: Quizá [esto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050965/using-dropzone-js-in-asp-net#answers-header) te ayude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas el articulo

[File upload in ASP.NET MVC using Dropzone JS and HTML5](http://venkatbaggu.com/file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dropzone-js-and-html5/)

veras al final un ejemplo en aspx

HTML: [WebFormDropzoneDemo.aspx](https://github.com/venkatbaggu/dropzonefileupload/blob/master/DropZoneFileUpload/DropZoneFileUpload/WebFormDropzoneDemo.aspx)

Code: [WebFormDropzoneDemo.aspx.cs](https://github.com/venkatbaggu/dropzonefileupload/blob/master/DropZoneFileUpload/DropZoneFileUpload/WebFormDropzoneDemo.aspx.cs)

entonces usa

```
<script src="Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //File Upload response from the server
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
        maxFiles: 2,
        url: "WebFormDropzoneDemo.aspx",
        init: function () { ....
```

define el aspx en el url y basicamente la subida del file se realiza en el `Page_Load`

```
public partial class WebFormDropzoneDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SaveUploadedFile(Request.Files);
        }
}
```

es alli donde toma el `Request.Files` que envia `dropzone`